# How to find a pair of chars within a string in c# netMF?

Tags: c#, string, search, .net-micro-framework

This has probably (somewhere) been asked before, but can't find any documentation on it (i have looked!).

Say I had declared a string like:

```
String Test = "abcdefg";
```

How would i go about searching the string to see if I could see "cd" anywhere in the string by searching through the string in pairs, like:

```
{ab}{bc}{cd}{de}{ef}{fg}
```

That is, if I split each of the values up, and searched for a pair of chars next to each other? Is there a built in function for this?

I have thought about using a char array for this, but it seems to (logically) be very 'heavy'/'slow'. Would there be a better solution to search this string?

**EDIT 1**

Once I see this "cd", I would then need to *doSomething()* at that position (which I have already implemented by using the `substring` method.

Comment: Is `String.Contains` what you are looking for? As in, `bool result = Test.Contains("cd");`.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think **string.Contains** is available in netMF?

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised. Then use `Test.IndexOf("cd") >= 0`.

Comment: @mikez, that would tell me it's there, but not where abouts it is (sorry, it answered the question, but i'm just bad at explaining what I was doing with the search) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String.IndexOf(...) != -1
```

For more infö, [read here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82b36546-55fb-48e6-ace5-c4f217de3c2c/any-workarounds-for-noneexistent-stringcontains-method?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs)

Comment: that would tell me it was there, but I would also need to find its location, too :(

Comment: @jbutler483 read the link neo posted, it does give you it's location. He's testing for `-1` as that's what will be returned if there is no location (i.e. it doesn't exist). +1 for only correct answer here.

Comment: Oh ok - I just thought it was a "1" or "-1" result. Sorry @neo!

Comment: @DeeMac could you possibly explain what happens if there are multiple results? Would this give just first index?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx `"Reports the zero-based index of the FIRST occurrence..."` Stop being lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from Neo, but in a loop to get all instances within the string:

```
string Test = "abcdefgcd";
int index = Test.IndexOf("cd");

while (index > -1)
{
    //DoSomething();
    index = Test.IndexOf("cd", ++index);
}
```

The first `IndexOf` checks for the existence of what you want, whilst the second `IndexOf` (in the loop) checks for a match *after* the last index.

In the above we find two matches and then the loop ends.

Comment: Note that I'm assuming .NETMF is similar to .NETCF in that it too is limited in it's framework support, but core functions are usually available [(from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in function that will do that.
having a for loop should do what you want.

something like that:

```
string str = string.empty;

for (i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {

  if (i != ch.length) {
     str += ch[i] + ch[i+1];
  }
}
```

also you can use regex however that wont be fast either.

In order to optimize this on a large scale you can implement byte shifting.

Answer (score -1):

The **ASCII** code of your string characters is your friend in this case, **full working example below**:

```
        var yourString = "abcdefg";

        var x = '\0';

        for (var i = 0; i < yourString.Length; i++)
        {

            //check whether i+1 index is not out of range
            if (i + 1 != yourString.Length)
            {
                var test = yourString[i + 1];
                x = yourString[i];

                if(x.ToString() + test.ToString() == "cd")
                {
                   Console.Write("Found at position " + i)
                }

            }
        }
```